# Getting new items added to an Observable Collection of a custom class

Tags: c#, json, wpf, reflection

I have a set of classes that I am using to deserialize JSON into. My program will periodically look for changes to this JSON file, and if it finds any, will push the new data to the properties of these classes using reflection.

I need to find any new items added to the collection of the Item2 class (SocialExportJSON.SocialExportData.Item2) after a successful update.

My JSON classes look like this (there are more but I want to avoid too big a wall of code):

```
public class Item2 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    private string type;

    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return type;
        }
        set
        {
            if (type != value)
            {
                type = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Type");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    private string id;

    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (id != value)
            {
                id = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("postedIso8601")]
    private string postedIso8601;

    public string PostedIso8601
    {
        get
        {
            return postedIso8601;
        }
        set
        {
            if (postedIso8601 != value)
            {
                postedIso8601 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("PostedIso8601");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("postedTimestamp")]
    private object postedTimestamp;

    public object PostedTimestamp
    {
        get
        {
            return postedTimestamp;
        }
        set
        {
            if (postedTimestamp != value)
            {
                postedTimestamp = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("PostedTimestamp");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("engagement")]
    private Engagement engagement;

    public Engagement Engagement
    {
        get
        {
            return engagement;
        }
        set
        {
            if (engagement != value)
            {
                engagement = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Engagement");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("source")]
    private Source2 source;

    public Source2 Source
    {
        get
        {
            return source;
        }
        set
        {
            if (source != value)
            {
                source = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Source");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("author")]
    private Author author;

    public Author Author
    {
        get
        {
            return author;
        }
        set
        {
            if (author != value)
            {
                author = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Author");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("content")]
    private Content content;

    public Content Content
    {
        get
        {
            return content;
        }
        set
        {
            if (content != value)
            {
                content = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Content");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("location")]
    private Location location;

    public Location Location
    {
        get
        {
            return location;
        }
        set
        {
            if (location != value)
            {
                location = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Location");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("publication")]
    private Publication publication;

    public Publication Publication
    {
        get
        {
            return publication;
        }
        set
        {
            if (publication != value)
            {
                publication = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Publication");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("metadata")]
    private Metadata metadata;

    public Metadata Metadata
    {
        get
        {
            return metadata;
        }
        set
        {
            if (metadata != value)
            {
                metadata = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Metadata");
            }
        }
    }

    //Event handling
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Updated");
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}

public class SocialExportData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [JsonProperty("dataType")]
    private string dataType;

    public string DataType
    {
        get
        {
            return dataType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (dataType != value)
            {
                dataType = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DataType");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    private int id;

    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (id != value)
            {
                id = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("story")]
    private Story story;

    public Story Story
    {
        get
        {
            return story;
        }
        set
        {
            if (story != value)
            {
                story = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Story");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("order")]
    private string order;

    public string Order
    {
        get
        {
            return order;
        }
        set
        {
            if (order != value)
            {
                order = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Order");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("lifetime")]
    private string lifetime;

    public string Lifetime
    {
        get
        {
            return lifetime;
        }
        set
        {
            if (lifetime != value)
            {
                lifetime = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Lifetime");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("maxAge")]
    private int maxAge;

    public int MaxAge
    {
        get
        {
            return maxAge;
        }
        set
        {
            if (maxAge != value)
            {
                maxAge = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MaxAge");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("maxSize")]
    private int maxSize;

    public int MaxSize
    {
        get
        {
            return maxSize;
        }
        set
        {
            if (maxSize != value)
            {
                maxSize = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MaxSize");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("consumeCount")]
    private int consumeCount;

    public int ConsumeCount
    {
        get
        {
            return consumeCount;
        }
        set
        {
            if (consumeCount != value)
            {
                consumeCount = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ConsumeCount");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("consumeInterval")]
    private int consumeInterval;

    public int ConsumeInterval
    {
        get
        {
            return consumeInterval;
        }
        set
        {
            if (consumeInterval != value)
            {
                consumeInterval = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ConsumeInterval");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("items")]
    private ObservableCollection<Item2> items;

    public ObservableCollection<Item2> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            if (items != value)
            {
                items = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
            }
        }
    }

    //Event handling
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Updated");
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}

public class SocialExportJSON : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    private string id;

    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (id != value)
            {
                id = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("ttl")]
    private int ttl;

    public int TTL
    {
        get
        {
            return ttl;
        }
        set
        {
            if (ttl != value)
            {
                ttl = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TTL");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("serial")]
    private long serial;

    public long Serial
    {
        get
        {
            return serial;
        }
        set
        {
            if (serial != value)
            {
                serial = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Serial");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("formatType")]
    private string formatType;

    public string FormatType
    {
        get
        {
            return formatType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (formatType != value)
            {
                formatType = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FormatType");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("modifiedIso8601")]
    private string modifiedIso8601;

    public string ModifiedIso8601
    {
        get
        {
            return modifiedIso8601;
        }
        set
        {
            if (modifiedIso8601 != value)
            {
                modifiedIso8601 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ModifiedIso8601");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("modifiedTimestamp")]
    private long modifiedTimestamp;

    public long ModifiedTimestamp
    {
        get
        {
            return modifiedTimestamp;
        }
        set
        {
            if (modifiedTimestamp != value)
            {
                modifiedTimestamp = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ModifiedTimestamp");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("timezone")]
    private string timezone;

    public string Timezone
    {
        get
        {
            return timezone;
        }
        set
        {
            if (timezone != value)
            {
                timezone = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Timezone");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("dataType")]
    private string dataType;

    public string DataType
    {
        get
        {
            return dataType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (dataType != value)
            {
                dataType = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DataType");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("exports")]
    private ObservableCollection<SocialExportData> exports;

    public ObservableCollection<SocialExportData> Exports
    {
        get
        {
            return exports;
        }
        set
        {
            if (exports != value)
            {
                exports = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Exports");
            }
        }
    }

    //Event handling
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Updated");
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

In another class, I have a method to deserialize to a global instance of my JSON class. It looks like this:

```
    public SocialExportJSON socialExportData;

    private async void DownloadAndDeserializeJSONAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            //Create a web client with the supplied credentials
            var exportClient = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uName, pw), Encoding = Encoding.UTF8};

            //Create a task to download the JSON string and wait for it to finish
            var downloadTask = Task.Run(() => exportClient.DownloadString(new Uri(eURL)));
            downloadTask.Wait();

            //Get the string from the task
            var JSONString = await downloadTask;

            //Create a task to deserialize the JSON from the last task
            var DeserializeTask = Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SocialExportJSON>(JSONString));
            DeserializeTask.Wait();

            SocialExportJSON sej = await DeserializeTask;

            //Check the timestamp first to see if we should change the data
            if(socialExportData == null)
            {
                //Get the data from the task
                socialExportData = await DeserializeTask;
            }
            else if(sej.ModifiedTimestamp != socialExportData.ModifiedTimestamp)
            {
                //Get the data from the task
                SocialExportJSON newData = await DeserializeTask;
                GetNewItems(newData);
                SetNewData(newData);

                //Call the exportUpdated event when the task has finished
                exportUpdated();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

In my SetNewData function, shown below, I use reflection to set the properties of my global class. Because I'm setting the whole collection rather than iterating through each of the properties in each of the classes, I can't use the CollectionChanged event to find new items.

```
    public void SetNewData(SocialExportJSON newData)
    {
        //Loop through each of the properties and copy from source to target
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in socialExportData.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (pi.CanWrite)
            {
                pi.SetValue(socialExportData, pi.GetValue(newData, null), null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way I can modify my SetNewData function in such a way that it calls CollectionChanged? If not, what would be the best way to go about getting any new additions to my collection of Item2?

Comment: Which one is your "global class" and how do you use it in your application?

Comment: I have a global instance of my root JSON class SocialExportJSON. I use it to access all the JSON data that's deserialized into it in my application

Comment: So you are creating a new instance of SocialExportJSON and expect what to happen exactly...? Which ObservableCollection and object instance are you talking about?

Comment: When I initialise an instance of the class that it's contained in, I use the initialiser for the class to call the DownloadAndDeserializeJSONAsync function to get the data from a JSON string and fill my global instance of the root JSON class from the start. I also deserialize any future updates made to the string to the same glboal JSON root class.

Comment: There are several ObservableCollections in your code...please provide a *minimal* example of your issue.

Comment: As mentioned in my question I'm focusing on the changes to ObservableCollection<Item2>. As it is part of a group of classes used to deserialize JSON to, I felt the need to include the root JSON object and the parent classes.

Comment: So where are you hooking up the event handler that you expect/want to get invoked...?

Comment: In my Main function. I create an instance of my class called SocialExport like so: `SocialExport s = new SocialExport("http://example.json", "example", "example");`. This class is where the global instance of my JSON class is contained, and my event handler is added like so `s.socialExportData.Exports[0].Items.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my Main function. I create an instance of my class called SocialExport like so:

```
SocialExport s = new SocialExport("http://example.json", "example", "example");.
```

> This class is where the global instance of my JSON class is contained, and my event handler is added like so

```
s.socialExportData.Exports[0].Items.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged;
```

Then you are hooking up an event handler for the `CollectionChanged` event for *that particular instance* of `ObservableCollection<Item2>`.

If you create a new `ObservableCollection<Item2>`, you obviously must hook up an event handler to this one as well. The event handler that is associated with the old object won't be invoked when new items are added to the new instance.

So whenever a new `ObservableCollection<Item2>` is created, using deserialization or not, you should hook up a new event handler.

You could probably do this in your `DownloadAndDeserializeJSONAsync` method. The other option would be to create only one instance of the collection and remove and add items from/to this one.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. As there is a global instance of my JSON class within my `SocialExport` class (namely `socialExportData`), my data is always set to the same instance of JSON classes, the new data simply overwrites the properties of the class (see my `SetNewData` function). I think the problem is that because I'm setting the properties of the root class directly, the `ObservableCollection<Item2>` property of the child class `SocialExportData` isn't being updated in the way it should, but I'm not sure how to get round this problem.

Comment: The DeserializeTask method returns a *new* SocialExportJSON, isn't it? So this is the problem. Or at least part of it.

Comment: No not quite, I create a temporary `SocialExportJSON` for the new data, and then I set the properties of the already created global instance to the properties of the temporary instance. This is done in the `SetNewData` method.

Comment: You are still setting the collection property to a new instance of an ObservableCollection which - as I mentioned in my answer - means that you should hook up another event handler to this particular instance.